# Post message on my friends wall with sdk 3.5 android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i want to post message on my friends wall , I got my friend list and their Id now i am using the below code but it not posting any message to my any of friend wall, i'll post my code, in my above code i am using a static id of my friends but it is not posting any message on my friends wall , if i replace the id with  my fb id then it is posting on my wall?

```
    private void getfriendlist() 
{ 
Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() 
{ // callback when session changes state @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
 @Override 
public void call(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) { if(session.isClosed())
{ 
Log.i("postStatusUpdate session.isClosed", "message not posted session is closed"); 
} if (session.isOpened()) 
{ // Log.i("session.isOpened", "session.isOpened"); //session.requestNewReadPermissions(newPermissionsRequest); 
if (!session.isOpened()) 
{ Session.OpenRequest openRequest = null; 
openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest(InvitefriendsActivity.this); 
if (openRequest != null) { //openRequest.setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.FRIENDS); openRequest.setPermissions(Arrays.asList("email,user_birthday,user_location,user_hometown,user_about_me,user_relationships,publish_stream,publish_actions,basic_info,status_update","friends_birthday","read_friendlists")); //openRequest.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK); session.openForRead(openRequest); 
} } 
Request.executeMyFriendsRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserListCallback() 
{ 
@Override public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users, Response response) { Log.d("AL",""+response.toString()); 
for (int i=0;i<users.size();i++)
{ //Log.d("AL",""+users.get(i).toString()); 
Log.d("AL",""+users.get(i).getId()); 
Log.d("AL",""+users.get(i).asMap().get("name")); 
Bundle params = new Bundle(); 
params.putString("message", "Hi "); 
params.putString("caption", "Hello"); 
Request request = new Request(session, "100005147887121/feed", params, HttpMethod.POST); RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request); task.execute(); } } }); } } }); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is related to requested Permissions. Are you (you Session) allowed to post to someone else Wall? You will find here a list of available permissions

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/

I think you need to request for 'publish_actions'

Regards

Michael

Comment: yes, i have given all the permissions and i have read all about permissions, but i have read the we can not post message on our friends wall after 6th feb due to some changes in the graph api,