# Post a message on facebook friend's wall in through Android applcation

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I want to post message on Facebook friend's wall through application. I am getting Facebook friend-list and some information like id, birthday, name, email,image,sex.

I am pasting here some code which is used

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
JSONObject attachment = new JSONObject();
   try {
        attachment.put("message", "Many more returns of the day");
       } catch (JSONException e) {
        }
   parameters.putString("attachment", attachment.toString());
   parameters.putString("target_id", iddd); // target Id in which you need to Post 
   parameters.putString("method", "stream.publish");
   String  response = authenticatedFacebook.request(parameters);       
   Log.v("response", response);
```

After run it I am getting this errors:

> "V/response(1420): {"error_code":101,"error_msg":"Invalid application
>   ID.","request_args":[{"key":"method","value":"stream.publish"},{"key":"format","value":"json"},{"key":"target_id","value":"100000739061115"},{"key":"attachment","value":"{\"message\":\"Many
>   more returns of the day\"}"}]}"

My question is:

1. Is is possible to post any message through application in Facebook friend's wall ?
   if yes please provide some method.

Thanks in advance
Please Help

Answer (score 0):

After reading a few questions like this one on the internet, it seems that Facebook does not allow any longer to publish on a friend's wall via their SDK since February 2013.
Sources:
[Source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21794327/post-message-on-my-friends-wall-with-sdk-3-5-android?answertab=votes#tab-top)
[Source 2](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/issues/325)